# How to setup hook for "hg branch"?

Tags: mercurial, branch, hook

I want to write a hook that performs some actions each time I run `hg branch branch_name` (e.g. set "In progress" status for a JIRA ticket), but I can't find anything that runs during branching. Is there a way I can do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The is a `pre-<command>` hook (with a hyphen) for each command.  Note that is is distinct from any hook that may exist without a hyphen, sush as `precommit`.

Thus you can do:

```
[hooks]
pre-bookmark = /usr/bin/notify_jira.sh ${HG_ARGS#bookmark }
```

to invoke:

```
/usr/bin/notify_jira.sh PROJ-415
```

when you run:

```
hg bookmark PROJ-415
```

Full details on the generic `pre-<command>` (and `post-<command>`) hooks can be found on the  [hgrc](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#hooks) man page.

It also looks like `pushkey` hook might do what you want, but `pre-bookmark` (or better, `post-bookmark`) is probably more straightforward.

Comment: `post-branch` was what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: Err, yeah, I see now you said branch not bookmark.  (That said, for per-bug work consider using bookmarks and not branches): http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/StandardBranching#Don.27t_treat_branch_names_as_disposable